# Twitter scraping of older tweets

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am doing a project in which I needed to get tweets from twitter, and I used the twitter API but it only gives tweets from 7-9 days old but I want a few months older tweets as well. So I decided to scrape Twitter using Beautifulsoup and later selenium, but when parsing it is not returning the elements but rather the veiwsource of the entire webpage. Please help!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
f=requests.get("https://twitter.com/search?q=%23......%20until%3A2020-02-07%20since%3A2020-01-01&src=typed_query").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')

print(soup)

name = soup.find_all('span', class_="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")

print(name)
```

the output from printing soup....i don't how to say it but its the viewsource but not the actual html code

```
{"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},t.t=function(e,n){if(1&n&&(e=t(e)),8&n)return e;if(4&n&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var d=Object.create(null);if(t.r(d),Object.defineProperty(d,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&n&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)t.d(d,o,function(n){return e[n]}.bind(null,o));return d},t.n=function(e){var n=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return t.d(n,"a",n),n},t.o=function(e,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,n)},t.p="https://abs.twimg.com/responsive-web/web/",t.oe=function(e){throw e};var i=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],c=i.push.bind(i);i.push=n,i=i.slice();for(var l=0;l<i.length;l++)n(i[l]);var u=c;d()}([]),window.__SCRIPTS_LOADED__.runtime=!0;
//# sourceMappingURL=runtime.cc3200a4.js.map
```

Selenium output in the same as well

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) 
driver.get("https://twitter.com")

email = driver.find_element_by_name('session[username_or_email]')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('session[password]')

email.send_keys('......')
password.send_keys("......")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)

driver.get('https://twitter.com/search?q=%23....%20until%3A2020-02-07%20since%3A2020-01-01&src=typed_query')
time.sleep(1)

print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetOldTweets3](https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/) enables you to extract historical tweets and filter based on multiple criteria i.e. time frame, location, handle, or search query without any API key prerequisites.

E.g.

```
  import GetOldTweets3 as got

  # Tweet params
  search_term = 'china trade war'
  start_date = '2017-01-01'
  end_date = '2020-01-01'
  
  # Define historical tweets criteria
  tweet_criteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername('reuters') \
                                            .setQuerySearch(search_term) \
                                            .setSince(start_date) \
                                            .setUntil(end_date) \
                                            
  # Return tweets based on tweet criteria
  tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweet_criteria)
    
  tweets.text
```

Note that you can access further tweet attributes such as hashtags, retweets etc through the `tweet` variable, for example:

```
other_tweet_attributes = [[tweet.username, tweet.hashtags for tweet in tweets]]
```

Comment: Seems like this is broken now - there is a work around here that seems to work https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98 using snscrape.modules.twitter