# list of working methods to scrape 4y+ historical Twitter tweets from users in 2022

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, twitter, twitterapi-python

It seems Twitter made lots of changes to API and Webapp so many methods that used to work in the past do not work anymore.

Which method does work as of today (April 2022) to scrape historical tweets from **specific users** at least the last 4+ years?

- Selenium scraping: open https://www.twitter.com/ and scroll down until you have the history you need

  - **not working**, only 1 month data
- https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/ - [Twitter scraping of older tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62655315/twitter-scraping-of-older-tweets)

  - **seems to have stopped working?** https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98
- Twitter API v2, Academic Research, full archive (free): https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api

  - **?**
- Twitter Premium API 1.1 full archive (paid): https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/search-api/overview

  - **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python based library named [twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint). It's an un-official sdk for twitter public API. you won't require twitter developer account or any access token.

`Twint` can help you in getting previous tweets and with some advanced controls.

If you feel some rate restriction from twitter for a large number of tweets, try breaking your search into smaller chunks.
Like, `10-10-2021` to `17-10-2021` (bi-weekly)

I have a sample github repo for that. [Link](https://github.com/saqe/Tweets-Scraper-by-user)

Hopefully, this can help!

Comment: CAUTION: the --since --until flags do not work properly, you have to set --until <maxdate> and work yourself backwards recursively. After around 50-100 tweets you run into some kind of ip block. Either use a proxy or you need to write a retry logic!